# No enviar action si algun input esta vacio php

Tags: php, php5

tengo mi front del login donde envio los campos ingresados para un query, pero quiero validar que si dichos campos son vacios no los envie y no se mueva de pagina , simplemente lance un mensaje de error, en este caso lo estoy haciendo con la libreria swal2, de preferencia que no recargue la pagina solo valide y si estan vacios o erroneos ahi se queda, pero si tiene datos ingresados y aparte existen en la bd deje hacer el query y posteriormente dejara entrar al index.php, PERO aqui el problema es que aunque puse el evento Onclick() no valida, envia directamente a log.php a hacer el query, esto porque? 
espero me puedan ayudar, saludos

```
        <form action="log.php" form method="POST" >

                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input id="txt1" name="txt1" class="form-control input_user"  placeholder="Usuario">
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input id="txt2"type="password" name="txt2" class="form-control input_pass"  placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <br>


                </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Entrar" onclick="Llamarswal()">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>



<?php
function Llamarswal(){
    if(empty($_POST['txt1'])  || empty($_POST['txt2'])){
         echo "<script> swal({
   title: 'Oooops...',
   text: 'Llena todos los campos!',
   type: 'error',
 });</script>";
    }
}
?>


</body>



</html>
```

Comment: no es mejor usar un required en los inputs?

Comment: Mm tal vez pero preferiria que saliera el alert de swal

Comment: Pero vale, digamos que asi lo resuelvo pero y cuando mete datos invalidos? o sea que no estan en la base de datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás validando en PHP variables de tipo POST en el evento click, este evento se ejecuta antes del submit, si aún no se ha enviado la información del formulario (no se ha ejecutado aún el submit), estas variables POST SIEMPRE estarán vacías, y bueno en tu código se ve que Llamarswal() no tiene un exit, lo cual permitiría terminar la ejecución sin que llegue a ejecutarse log.php.

Te aconsejo que realices la validación en el onclick, pero a través de javascript puro, en caso que no pase la validación de campos, retornes un false, de esta forma no se ejecutará el evento submit.

```
if (document.getElementById('txt1').value === '' || document.getElementById('txt1').value === '') {
    swal({
      title: 'Oooops...',
      text: 'Llena todos los campos!',
      type: 'error',
    });
    return false;
}
```

Y recuerda que en el onclick debes poner lo siguiente

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Entrar" onclick="return Llamarswal()">Login</button>
```

Es necesario incluir la palabra clave "return" para que no se ejecute el submit.